# "Getting somewhere with one's life" meaning

Tags: meaning, metaphors

In More than Cool Reason book by George Lakoff, I came up with the phrase "Getting somewhere with one's life" which I don't know the meaning. Here is the whole sentence:

First, without such a conceptual metaphor as LIFE IS A JOURNEY, there would be no conceptual unity to such ordinary conventional expressions as "making one's way in life," "giving one's life some direction," "getting somewhere with one's life," and so on.

Can anyone help with the meaning of "Getting somewhere with one's life"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, getting somewhere means to achieve some kind of success, to accomplish something  (in one's life).

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/get-somewhere